# Compactification of Topological Function Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, geometric-topology, compactification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $C(X,Y)$ be a topological function space of all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$.  Suppose there exists a function $g$ such that we do not know if it is continuous or not, but we want to make $g$ continuous.  Of course, we do not know a priori whether $g$ belongs to $C(X,Y)$ or not, but we want to make $g$ an element of $C(X,Y)$.

Is there a way to artificially add $g$ to $C(X,Y)$ and make $g$ a continuous function?

Comment: Are you hoping for anything beyond adding inverse images of opens in $Y$ under $g$, and taking the topology generated by the original opens and these inverse images? Or, oppositely, you could exclude any opens in $Y$ whose inverse images under $g$ are not open in $X$...

Comment: You will have to change the topology of either $X$ or $Y$, as paul suggested. But than it also change $C(X, Y)$.

Comment: BTW a compactfication of a function space will not always be a fucntion space again.

Answer (score 1):

The topologies on $X$ and $Y$ are given and so it's completely determined if any $f: X \to Y$ is continuous or not. So **as a set** $C(X,Y)$ is fixed. So the simple answer is **no**.

But, if you enlarge the topology on $X$, more functions can be continuous, so that $C(X,Y)$ is possibly larger (but it's not the same space anymore, because it depends on the given topologies on $X$ and $Y$).

Given any topology $\mathcal{T}_X$ and $g: X \to Y$ we can give define a topology $\mathcal{T}(g)$ with subbase $$\mathcal{T} \cup \{g^{-1}[O]: O \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$$ to get a minimal topology that extends the one on $X$ and makes $g$ continuous as a map $(X, \mathcal{T}(g)) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ so that the new $C(X,Y)$ contains the old one and also $g$.

It might also possible to shrink the topology on $Y$ to get a similar effect.